# How to Create installation shield for MFC(VC++) Project?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to Create installation shield for MFC(VC++) Project ?
I dont have any idea on installation shield.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean InstallShield - which is a commerical installer. Make sure you really need this installer - Visual Studio now comes with some built in installers that do work. InstallShield is very full featured, and a bit of learning curve -